# How to return data along with a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, state-machine

This function handles stock account data sequentially, like a state machine, in order to place a sell order.

I need to pass the account data to each state, and I don't want to store it in global variable. How do I achieve that? Am I using promises inappropriately?

**Note** that each call like get_account, delete_order are async calls that **returns promises**. And they shouldn't pass along irrelevant data.

```
function sell_stocks(){
    get_account_info().then(account => {
        if (account.orders.length > 0){
            return delete_orders(account.orders);
        } else {
            return "continue";
        }
    }).then(data => {
        // Now I need variable "account"
        place_sell_order(account.volume); //account undefined
    }).catch(msg => {
        //handle error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing

`return delete_orders(account.orders).then((data) => [data,account]);`

And

`then(([data, account]) => {...})`

Or if you just want the account data

`return delete_orders(account.orders).then(() => account);`

And

```
function sell_stocks(){
    get_account_info().then(account => {
        if (account.orders.length > 0){
            return delete_orders(account.orders).then(()=> account);
        } else {
            return account;
        }
    }).then(account => {
        place_sell_order(account.volume);
    }).catch(msg => {
        //handle error
    });
}
```

Or with async/await

```
async function sell_stocks(){
  try {
    const account = await get_account_info();
    if (account.orders.length > 0) {
      await delete_orders(account.orders)
    }
    return place_sell_order(account.volume);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`At sell_stocks ${e}`);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will actually do the job. Thanks!

Comment: @guest271314 It returns a promise with no data.

Comment: @Aus Then `data` at code at Answer will be `undefined`, yes, thus making it not necessary to define `data` at all?

Comment: @August Note, parentheses are necessary surrounding `[data, account]` at `then([data, account] => {...})` to avoid syntax error

Comment: @Aus Why do you state that you do not want to use "cascade" though propose editing the present Answer to include "cascade" `.then()`?

Answer (score 0):

Return `account` from first `.then()` to access `account` at chained `.then()`

```
function sell_stocks(){
    return get_account_info().then(account => {
        if (account.orders.length > 0){
            return account
        } else {
            return "continue";
        }
    }).then(data => {
        // Now I need variable "account"
        return delete_orders(data.orders)
               .then(() => place_sell_order(data.volume))
    }).catch(msg => {
        //handle error
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, but I need to wait for orders to be deleted first. That's why I want to return it alongside with the promise. And that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: What does `delete_orders(account.orders)` return?

Comment: it returns nothing, I'm just waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @Aus my guess is it should return a promise as well.

Comment: And note that this code snippet is short, I can't cascade .then() often. I prefer chained .then()

Comment: @PhilFilippak yes sorry, it returns a promise but no data I mean.

Comment: The code at Answer should provide expected result. `data`:`account`

Comment: @Aus What do you mean by "cascade"? If `delete_orders` does not return a value how do you expect to get a reference to the parameter passed to the function at `.then()` chained to the function call?

Comment: In cascade I meant the code branches horizontally. like the .then() that handles delete_order promise. However it seems inevitable.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean?

Comment: cascade: call1().then(data => { call2().then()...})   while chain: call1().then(...).then(...).then(...)....  matter of readability.

Comment: There is no issue with the readability of the code at Answer. You could alternatively use `async/await` to avoid using chained or "cascade" `.then()` altogether  if you are trying to perform all of the procedures within a single block

Comment: Agree, but this is just a snippet, the actual state machine is much worse, partially my fault.

Comment: Is the requirement of the Question to resolve the issue described at Question or to write code in a certain manner, irrespective of addressing the actual Question? Using chained `.then()` is not mentioned at original Question as part of requirement; "cascade" and the definition that you attached to the term is not mentioned at original Question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I hope you are not taking offense, I am thankful for your help!, the question was about returning data along with a promise, my langue sometimes fails me to explain.

Comment: @Aus Why do you describe not being able to "cascade" `.then()` though propose editing an Answer to include your own definition of "cascade" `.then()` at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17625096 ? Note, that is the same pattern used at the present Answer

Comment: @Aus  _"I can't cascade .then()"_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743286/how-to-return-data-along-with-a-promise/46743331#comment80432839_46743331, _"cascade: call1().then(data => { call2().then()...})"_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743286/how-to-return-data-along-with-a-promise/46743331#comment80433056_46743331,  though your  proposed [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17625096) to Answer by August is `.then(account => {if (account.orders.length > 0){return delete_orders(account.orders).then(()=> account)`, the  "cascade" pattern, yes ?

Comment: @Aus No offense taken. Curious why you described not being able to use "cascade" `.then()` pattern though apparently composed your own solution to the inquiry using "cascade" `.then()` pattern?

Comment: Apparently there is no way to do what I needed without delete_order().then().  However in August's case, it is used to forward the variable to the chained .then(), while in your method, it is used to call place_order which is a method I'm aware of. In my opinion August answer is closer to the question specifications even if you regard it as trivial. Both answers are helpful and valid, it is a personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

You can do as follows:

```
function sell_stocks() {
    get_account_info().then((account) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (account.orders.length > 0) {
                resolve(delete_orders(account.orders));
            } else {
                resolve('continue');
            }
        }).then(data => {
            // Now I need variable "account"
            place_sell_order(account.volume); //account undefined
        }).catch(msg => {
            //handle error
        });
    });
}
```

Thus keeping the `account` variable in the local scope.

Comment: Why is `Promise` constructor necessary?

Comment: In all these cases, we're cascading .then() instead of chaining it. May be it is the way forward, although the indentation will pass a screen width in a larger state machine.

Comment: It's not but it first occurred to me to use it.

Comment: @PhilFilippak `.then()` returns a new `Promise` object, `Promise` constructor is not necessary

Comment: @Aus you could split it in several functions then.

Comment: That is a possibility, I don't like the way I've written it either.